# Proving a series of functions converges to a differentiable on $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Ok. I've been staring at this problem for a long while now and I'm not even sure i'm properly understanding it. The problem is as follows:

Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of functions, each continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R$. For each $k \in \mathbb N$, there exists a constant $C_k$ > 0 such that $|f_n(x)| \leq C_k$ and $|f'_n(x)| \leq C_k$ for $|x| \leq k$. Prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{xf_n(x)^2}{4^n}$$ converges to a function differentable on $\mathbb R$

I know that each function in $(f_n)$ must be continuous, and that $f_n(x)^2$ should also be differentiable since it's just multiplying two differentable functions together. Yet I see no reason why I need the data about $C_k$. I thought maybe the M-Test would be involved to show that that series converges, but I see no way to prove that adding the constants has a limit of less than infinity. I've hit a road block everywhere I've tried and I know this is the type of problem I will see on the final. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I don't even know what to try next.

Comment: What does the $M$-test give you on the interval $[-k,k]$?

Comment: I figured out how to use induction to show the M test works on that interval, so long as my M's don't diverge, but for my choice of $M_k = \frac{k(C_k)^2}{4^k}, I get a divergent series. Any suggestions on M?

Comment: $k$ and $n$ are independent. On the interval $[-k,k]$, **all** the $f_n$ and their derivatives are bounded by $C_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is that the space $C^1[a,b]$ is complete. That is, if $f_n \in C^1[a,b]$ is Cauchy (with norm $\|f\|= \|f\|_\infty+\|f'\|_\infty$, then there is some $f \in C^1[a,b]$ such that $f_n \to f$ (which means
$\|f-f_n\|_\infty \to 0, \|f'-f_n'\|_\infty \to 0$).

Pick some $k$, and let $g_n(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{xf_i(x)^2}{4^i}$.
We have $g_n'(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f_i(x)^2+ 2 x f_i(x)f_i'(x)}{4^i}$.
Clearly $g_n \in C^1[-k,k]$.
Note that $|\frac{xf_i(x)^2}{4^i}| \le {k C_k^2 \over 4^i }$ and
$|\frac{f_i(x)^2+ 2 x f_i(x)f_i'(x)}{4^i} | \le {(2k+1)C_k^2 \over 4^i}$.

Use the Weierstraß M-test to show that $g_n$ is Cauchy in the $C^1$ norm. Hence $g_n \to g \in C_1[-k,k]$.

Since $k$ was arbitrary, we have a continuously differentiable $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $g_n(x) \to g(x), g_n'(x) \to g'(x)$.

Comment: Ok, I think i'm starting to get it, i'm just having trouble proving that the sum of the M's is less than infinity, taking each $M_k$ to be $\frac{k(C_k)^2}{4^k}, every test i've tried has a finite radius of convergence for the series, which can't be true for the proof to be right. Both ratio and root tests for convergence of the series of M's I end up with R=4. Any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Actually..i'm not getting it at all. What is your $C^1$ referring to?

Comment: Functions that are continuously differentiable. Feel free to ask questions, I will elaborate when I get a chance. I wrote the above to give a hint rather than a full answer.

Comment: I had to go back over a few things again, but I think i get it now. Thank you so much for your guidance without just giving me the solution. I feel much better now.

Comment: Glad to help, these things can be a little tricky.